# Exchange 2016 won't recreate HealthMailboxes for Monitoring

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

I needed to repair some corrupt Monitoring HealthMailboxes.  I've followed the instructions from numerous articles indicating I should stop the Microsoft Exchange Health Manager (and Recovery) services, disable the monitoring mailboxes, delete the HealthMailbox users from AD (within ADUC "Microsoft Exchange System Objects\Monitoring Mailboxes"), await an AD sync, then restart the services and the MS Exchange Health Manager will recreate the mailboxes.

i.e. [How to fix damaged or corrupt Health Mailbox on Exchange 2016](https://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/253-resolved-how-to-fix-damaged-or-corrupt-health-mailbox-on-exchange-2016.html)

[Exchange 2013/2016 Monitoring Mailboxes](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/exchange-2013-2016-monitoring-mailboxes/ba-p/611004)

My issue is that Exchange 2016 will not recreate the HealthMailboxes.  HealthMailbox users are not created in AD "Microsoft Exchange System Objects\Monitoring Mailboxes" and "Get-Mailbox -Monitoring" returns no results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all required services of your Exchange 2016 server running? **[Required services on Exchange 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/deployment-ref/services-overview?view=exchserver-2016#exchange-services-on-mailbox-servers)**

Is there any error in the **Event Viewer** after you restarted MS Exchange HM service to generate Health(monitor) mailboxes?

Based on my research, I found a similar thread: **[Exchange 2013 has no HealthMailboxes attached to it - how to recreate when the OU Monitoring Mailboxes does not exist in AD](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/266c3061-df8a-4f6e-b942-4a6a781357dc/exchange-2013-has-no-healthmailboxes-attached-to-it-how-to-recreate-when-the-ou-monitoring?forum=exchangesvrdeploy)**, please try to run the **[prepare AD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/prepare-ad-and-domains?view=exchserver-2016#step-2-prepare-active-directory)** cmdlet in the Command Prompt/PowerShell and see the result.

Comment: Yes, all services are running properly.  Ivan, since I posted this, Exchange did seem to wake up and actually create the mailboxes (didn't change anything additional on my side).  Thank you!